# How to give spacing between rating bar stars android?

Tags: android, ratingbar

Hi I am using custom rating bar with custom images. I need to provide space between stars. When I increase minimum height and maximum height, star image remains same.

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" 
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/allreviews"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Rating"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

        <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/reviewallrating"
        style="@style/customRatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/allreviews"
        android:isIndicator="false"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="0.1" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

styles:
    
        @drawable/star_rating_bar_full
        12dip
        12dip

```
   star_rating_bar_full.xml:

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
      android:drawable="@drawable/star_ratingbar_full_empty" />
   <!--     <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
      android:drawable="@drawable/star_ratingbar_full_empty" /> -->
      <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
      android:drawable="@drawable/star_ratingbar_full_filled" />
      </layer-list>

star_ratingbar_full_empty:

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <!-- This is the rating bar drawable that is used to
   show a filled cookie. -->
    <selector
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:state_pressed="true"
  android:state_window_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/star_gray" />

  <item android:state_focused="true"
  android:state_window_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/star_gray" />

 <item android:state_selected="true"
  android:state_window_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/star_gray"/>

 <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_gray" />

 </selector>
star_ratingbar_fullfilled.xml:
```

```
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
  android:state_window_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/yellow_star" />

  <item android:state_focused="true"
  android:state_window_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/yellow_star" />

  <item android:state_selected="true"
  android:state_window_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/yellow_star" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/yellow_star" />
```

I used style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle" in styles but still output remains same.
  [image]

Comment: You could simply add some empty space to the **left and right** sides of your PNGs. By the way.... how are `minimum height and maximum height` related to the **width** you want to act on?

Comment: okay. i used rating bar width as match_parent but it goes with multiple stars ie more than 5 stars and size remains too small.

Comment: No. There's some communication problem. Leave the RatingBar's width as `wrap_content`. Increase the width of the grey and yellow PNGs in **GIMP** (or whatever **graphic editor** program you use). Just the canvas, without stretching the star.

Comment: I collected my comments into an answer, so that you can accept it and remove the question from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Comment: I have added a feature request, please vote for it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230511

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could simply add some empty space to the left and right sides of your PNGs.

That is, increase the width of the grey and yellow PNGs in GIMP (or whatever graphic editor program you use).
Just the canvas, without stretching the star icon.

Comment: But what if you use tint color, but not PNG files?

Comment: You can try, it could work. But I went the quick and easy way ;)

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Drawable for the stars. Make sure your drawable have some left padding according to your requirement in the png image.

Otherwise through code its not working. Some days back I stuck with the same problem. I gone through by using the left padded image. Hope it will work.